# Truncate data in ActiveAdmin index page

Tags: activeadmin

Is it possible to truncate the data displayed for an attribute in an ActiveAdmin index page? One of my attributes contains a lot of text so it makes the layout of the table on the index page hard to look at.

I'm trying this...

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index do
      column :id
      column :title
      column :body do |body|
        truncate(body, omision: "...", length: 100)
      end
      column :author
    end
end
```

But I get the error that the method 'truncate' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to hide a column, you can use any helpers in ActiveAdmin, here is my case with User comments in ../admin/user/:id:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register User do
    panel "Coments" do
      table_for user.comments do
        column :id
        column "comment" do |comment|
          truncate(comment.content, omision: "...", length: 100)
        end
        column "created at" do |comment|
          l comment.created_at, format: :long
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

will result in:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt..."

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index do
      column :id
      column :title
      column :body do |post|
        truncate(post.body, omision: "...", length: 100)
      end
      column :author
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to adapt your example. But it doesn't work from reason. I get this error... "undefined method 'truncate'" I edited the original question so you can see the code.

Comment: see edited answer, I just tested in my app, should work with copy/paste

Comment: @niftygrifty See [Undefined method 'truncate' in model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29055796/1350377).

Try `post.body.truncate 100` instead of `truncate(post.body, length: 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to not show that column in index page

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id do |item| eval"link_to item.id, admin_#{item.class.name.to_s.underscore}_path(item)" rescue nil end rescue nil
    column :name
    # ... all other columns you want to display
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at

    default_actions
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! It appears that what I'm specifically asking for doesn't yet exist. But your solution works well for me in this case, so I'm going with it! @James

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but a simpler way to do it is to:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  index do
      column :id
      column :title
      column :body do |post|
        post.body[0...100]
      end
      column :author
    end
end
```