# Rails: Undefined method `truncate' in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method in my model which crops the record's description, but for an unknown reason the truncate method does not work:

```
def cropped_description
  nb_words_max = 500
  if description.length > nb_words_max
    truncate(description, :length => nb_words_max, :separator => ' ') + " ..."
  else
    description
  end
end
```

Anyone sees what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what you're storing in the description variable?

Comment: Of course. The description represents the record's description. For now, it contains Lorem Ipsum text to test it.

Comment: For instance, one of my records contains [this](http://pastebin.com/UH4A222Q).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using it wrong, you should be calling this method on a `String`.  See [`truncate`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)'s signature.

Use:

```
if description.length > nb_words_max
  description.truncate(nb_words_max, :separator => ' ') + " ..."
else
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the answer I was looking for. Although, you should remove `:length =>`, because it generates an error: `comparison of Fixnum with Hash failed` since `length` is not part of the method's options.

Comment: The conditional is not necessary per the docs.  It is already preformed by the truncate function.

Comment: @JarvisJohnson, missed to follow the links in answer and comment in mu's answer?

Answer (score 6):

In rails include:

```
 include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

but if you want to tested in Ruby irb:

```
 require 'action_view'
 include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Comment: It's bad to require action_view in model.

Comment: I know. Is just that I tested in ruby irb. I put it just in case.

Comment: You can also get this from ActiveSupport, with `require 'active_support/core_ext/string'`, see https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String:truncate

Answer (score 1):

The [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) method you're looking for is a view helper so it won't be available inside your model method, you should be calling `truncate` from inside a view. Also, if view helper will adding ellipses for you so you can just say:

```
<%= truncate(m.description, :length => 500, :separator => ' ') %>
```

Comment: Why can it not be available in model? Please see: http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate.

Comment: @vee Not available in the model because it looked like they were trying to use the `truncate` view helper rather than the String method. Note that the view helper *does* have a `:length` option.