# Rails: Undefined method `truncate' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to perform this in the rails console, following the instructions at [Rails API ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)
I already found a solution of my problem at the following [Stackoverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055618/undefined-method-truncate-in-model#29055796), but I though the question could be useful to be posted.
If you want me to delete it, just tell me.

1. I wanted to create an `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` in my rails console

   ```
   texthelper = ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
   => ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
   ```
2. I create a string

   ```
   string = "I want to call the truncate method"
   => "I want to call the truncate method"
   ```
3. I want to call the truncate method, in my console on this string.

   ```
   truncate(string, length: 25, omission: '... (continued)')
   => "And they f... (continued)"
   ```

When I input in the console:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17, separator: ' ')
```

I receive

```
undefined method `truncate' for main:Object
```

The whole idea come from this post..
[Undefined method `truncate' in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055618/undefined-method-truncate-in-model#29055796)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer at the following discussion [Undefined method `truncate' in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055618/undefined-method-truncate-in-model#29055796)

I should have included the ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper in my rails console with the following command

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Then I could call the truncate method.

```
truncate(string, length: 17, separator: ' ')
=> "this is a tesf..."
```

My understanding now is that with the `include` command, the methods from `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` are now available in the console. `truncate` method can be executed on `text`.

Answer (score 5):

For rails 6 and ruby 2.6.*, there might have some problems and at-least I faced an error of undefined error in doing truncate of rich-text. So, ActionText and Truncate, I have found the solution, it might be useful =>

```
<%= truncate(strip_tags(blog.body.to_s), length: 450) %>
```

Comment: an alternative approach for ActionText `<%= strip_tags(post.body.to_s).truncate_words(50) %>`

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Ahsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021199/10907864)

When working on a **Rails 6** application, I tried adding calling the `truncate` method on a view that has an ActionText attribute.

This is it, I had a Model called **About** with an attribute of `title` and an ActionText attribute of `body`.

So when I try to call the `truncate` method on the ActionText attribute of `body` in my views using this:

```
<%= about.body.truncate(30) %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `truncate' for #<ActionText::RichText:0x00007fe5c4828488>
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Following [Ahsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59021199/10907864), I simply modified the line of code to this:

```
<%= truncate(strip_tags(about.body.to_s), length: 30) %>
```

and it worked like charm.

You can read up more on the truncate method in the Official Rails documentation: [ActionView Truncate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps in rails console:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
truncate(string, length: 25, omission: '... (continued)')
=> "Once upon ... (continued)"
```

Here "ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper" is module provides a set of methods for formatting and transforming strings.

Truncate method is in TextHelper Module so you have to include it in console.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would be happy to accept your answer if you are willing to give me an explanation by editing your post of what is this `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` and what effectively happens when I include it in my rails console